# TypeScript accessing inherited class`s methods and properties

Tags: typescript, inheritance

I have a class:

```
export class OneComponent {
  public name: string;
  public age = 5;
    speak() {
      console.log('speaking native language');
    }
    }
```

and have second class:

```
import { OneComponent } from '../one/one.component';


export class TwoComponent extends OneComponent {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.call();
    this.speak();
  }
  call() {
    console.log(this.age);
  }
 }
```

I use 'this' word to access speak() method  from class OneComponent in class TwoComponent. I also can make it by creating a new() instance. Could anybody explain me why can I access inherited class without creating an instance of it? I searched in the internet and there's only examples with instance creating. In which case should I create a new instance and in which shouldn't? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The TwoComponent instance is effectively an extended / specialised instance of OneComponent. So from the instance of TwoComponent you can access properties and methods that are defined in OneComponent

Answer (score 0):

When you create an instance of a derived class you are also creating an instance of the base classes, too. You see the call to `super()` in your constructor? It's calling the constructor of the inherited class, to initialise it.

Of course, the instance of the inherited class is also the instance of the derived class. when you call `new TwoComponent()` then you are creating that instance (which in the constructor is reflected by the `this` constant). That instance is automatically filled with the properties of `TwoComponent`, which, of course, includes all the properties/methods of the base classes.